# How to set custom JRE System library path value in Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to set the default value for the JRE system library in Spring Tool Suite and it's setting it to 1.6 version but I need it to be 1.6.0_xx by default.

I have set the value for JAVA_HOME to be C:..\java\jdk1.6.0_xx and in the PATH variable it set to C:..\java\jdk1.6.0_xx\bin. After I configured it this way, I was able to build my maven projects successfully via the command line but when I attempt to build the Maven project from STS I get this error

**Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object**

Is there any workaround for this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to `Window -> Preferences`
2. Once the preferences dialog appears, go to `Java -> Installed JRE`
3. Add your JRE, if it's not in the list, check-mark it, `Apply`, `OK`

Comment: In addition to that you can specify using the "Execution Environments" subsection in the preferences which installed JRE should be used as a default for the various JDK levels.

Comment: Your suggestion to set the default installed JRE within the "Execution Environments" section worked correctly ! Thanks